# How to read MySQL timestamp(6) into pandas?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a MySql table with timestamps that have a microsecond resolution:

```
+----------------------------+------+
| time                       | seq  | 
+----------------------------+------+
| 2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509 |    0 | 
| 2015-06-19 02:17:57.934171 |   10 |
+----------------------------+------+
```

I want to read it into a pandas Dataframe. Using

```
import pandas as pd
con = get_connection()
result = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM MyTable;", con=con)
print result
```

returns NaT (not a time):

```
    time  seq 
0   NaT    0  
1   NaT   10
```

How can I read it into a timestamp?

Comment: Can you give some additional information? 1) What is your pandas version? 2) what is `con`? Is it a sqlalchemy engine? Or a connection? (it should be an sqlalchemy engine) 3) Can you show the output of `con.execute(`"SELECT * FROM MyTable;").fetchall()``

Comment: @joris, 'it should be an sqlalchemy engine' is not necessarily true.  for `read_sql()`, a  `sqlite3` `DBAPI2` object  can be supplied, correct?

Comment: Ah yes, that is true! (not officially, but indeed works), but still, interesting to know. And the examples you give with `read_sql_table` will not work then. EDIT: note that sqlite is a exception, for this an DBAPI connection is officially supported, also for writing frames, for other database types it will only work for reading queries, not for reading or writing tables.

Comment: Here's the link to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) in case anyone is looking for it.

Comment: @joris: 1) pandas version = 0.16.2.  --- 2) `con` is the connection to the DB with the MySQLdb module: `con = MySQLdb.connect(host='1.2.3.4', db='mydb')`  ---  3) `con.execute` is not possible because `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! For the third one, can you try `cur = con.cursor(); cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable;").fetchall()`? (the `execute` method is provided in a lot of drivers, but apparantly not MySQLdb)

Comment: Other question: did you get the same result when using `pd.read_sql_table('MyTable', engine)` (this one only works when supplying an sqlalchemy engine)

Comment: @joris: I never used an sqlalchemy engine. Only the `MySQLdb` module.

Comment: I would recommend to use SQLAlchemy (it is easy to install). For writing to SQL it will be a required dependency (but always in combination with your driver, in your case `MySQLdb`), for reading queries as above it will keep working without. Did you try the `cur = con.cursor(); cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable;").fetchall()` ?

Answer (score 10):

In general, to convert timestamps, you can to use the `pandas.to_datetime()`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime('2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509')
Timestamp('2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509')
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql), when reading in from SQL, you can explicitly force columns to be parsed as dates:

```
pd.read_sql_table('data', engine, parse_dates=['Date'])
```

or more explicitly, specify a format string, or a dict of arguments to pass to `pandas.to_datetime()`:

```
pd.read_sql_table('data', engine, parse_dates={'Date': '%Y-%m-%d'})
```

or

```
pd.read_sql_table('data', engine, parse_dates={'Date': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}})
```

Adding a quick proof of concept.  NOTE, I am using `SQLITE`.  Assuming you are storing the timestamps as strings:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

datapoints = [{'ts': '2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509', 'seq': 0},
              {'ts':'2015-06-19 02:17:57.934171', 'seq': 10}]
metadata = MetaData()
mydata = Table('mydata', metadata,
    Column('ts', String),
    Column('seq', Integer),
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
ins = mydata.insert()
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(ins, datapoints)

foo = pd.read_sql_table('mydata', engine, parse_dates=['ts'])
print(foo)
```

outputs:

```
                           ts  seq
0  2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509    0
1  2015-06-19 02:17:57.934171   10
```

or, if you are storing them as datetime objects, it works the same (the code differences are me getting the data into a database in datetime format):

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, DateTime, MetaData
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

datapoints = [{'ts': datetime.strptime('2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), 'seq': 0},
              {'ts':datetime.strptime('2015-06-19 02:17:57.934171', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), 'seq': 10}]
metadata = MetaData()
mydata = Table('mydata', metadata,
    Column('ts', DateTime),
    Column('seq', Integer),
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
ins = mydata.insert()
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(ins, datapoints)

foo = pd.read_sql_table('mydata', engine, parse_dates=['ts'])
print(foo)
```

outputs the same:

```
                          ts  seq
0 2015-06-19 02:17:57.389509    0
1 2015-06-19 02:17:57.934171   10
```

Hope this helps.

***EDIT*** To *attempt* to address a concern of @joris, it is true `sqlite` stores all `datetime` objects as strings, however the built-in adapter automatically converts these back to `datetime` objects when fetched.  Extending the second example with:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
s = select([mydata])
res = conn.execute(s)
row = res.fetchone()
print(type(row['ts']))
```

results in `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

Comment: I tried your examples, but it still leads to a `NaT`

Comment: I'll take another look when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @ThS, what type is your `time` stored as?  string or datetime?

Comment: Some notes: I don't know if the comparison with SQLite will be that useful, as this does not have a Datetime type (just stored as strings). Secondly, in the second case where you store them as 'datetime's (but it is just the column name), the explicit `parse_dates` should not be needed.

Comment: @joris - actually, from SQLite, it looks like I can omit the `parse_dates` from both versions... (just tested).  How would mySQL store the timestamps?  as strings?

Comment: Mysql has specific types for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. I ended up with a work-around, avoiding the TIMESTAMPS with fractional seconds. Not great, but it works.

Comment: Thanks @ThS.  Glad you found a workaround.  would still love to solve your problem though...  (darn OCD).

Comment: @ThS It should work, and if not this is a bug. If you want to help to solve the issue, can you please answer the questions I added in a comment on your question above?